# Who is the longest lived species in the United Federation of Planets?

Tags: star-trek

Klingon and Human seem to top out at about 100 years and the Vulcans make it to about 200. Is there a UFP member species who last longer?

Comment: @Ganesh What does someone's recommendation of Star Trek viewing order for young children have to do with, 'What is the longest lived species in the Federation?'? Nothing there remotely answers the question.

Comment: The UFP is a federation of **planets**, not **species**, as its name tells us. So what is a "member species"? Since the earth is a member of the Federation, does that make all earthly species "member species"? [Some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pando_(tree)) species can live for tens of thousands or maybe a million years, but maybe those have all gone extinct by Star Trek time?

Comment: Not asking about all species in the Star Trek universe, just member species in the Federation.

Comment: Did I miss a deleted comment here or something?

Comment: Technically the Klingons aren't part of the Federation. And they can apparently live, and be able bodied, past 100 years of age, as evidenced by [Kang](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kang).

Comment: @Xantec Fair enough. They're not official members but they're always hanging around; kind of like that crazy uncle who keeps getting you into trouble.

Comment: @Xantec I think I remember hearing somewhere that [Kor](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Kor) was around 150 when he died.  And he was going senile, so that seems to be around their limit if I'm right.

Comment: Heavy drinking, constantly starting fights, making inappropriate comments, mildly xenophobic, and possessing an intense hatred of small, fluffy animals; yep, my uncle is definitely a Klingon.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - not unless he can recite Sheakspeare

Comment: @DVK: Does slurring count as a recitation?

Comment: Not UFP members, but bioplasmic organisms seem to be very very long lived. [Bevvox](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bevvox) is "a few millenia" old. and the [telepathic pitcher plant](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Telepathic_pitcher_plant) is about 200,000 years old.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a species that is definitely part of the Federation and is TV-Canon, I submit to you [The Trill](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Trill).

Though this depends on what you mean by 'longest lived'.  Individual hosts certainly seem to have a limit on their lifespan, and non-joined Trill presumably also die within the same span, but judging by how frequently their symbiote can join, their effective lifetime of a joined Trill could be considered 'infinite' (there is no solid canonical lifespan established for the symbiote, but they seem to live at least as long as 500 years or more under ideal host conditions).

Comment: You mean _joined_ Trills, actually. The majority of Trills are not joined.

Comment: @MrLister I did say that it was their symbiotes specifically that could be considered to ahve an infinite lifespan, but I'll make that more clear.

Comment: Well, we know for sure they can live at least a rough 550 years, The [Dax](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dax_%28symbiont%29) symbiont apparently was born in the year 2018, and in [Children of Time](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Children_of_Time_%28episode%29) it had been on the planet for over 200 years.

Comment: @Zibbobz Of course - Trills. Forgot about them.  After poking around online a bit, it seems that Trill Symbiotes can live an estimated 500-1000+ years. This is speculative though. There's also speculation that the symbiote will eventually grow too large to be joined with a Humanoid Trill host and therefore limit lifespan somewhat. I can't find a definitive lifespan expectation.

Comment: I had not thought of the Trill, but even they don't live as long as the Horta. There are definitely species which do, but none that I know of who are members of the Federation.

Answer (score 11):

The [Horta](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Horta), who join the Federation after the events of [*The Devil in the Dark*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Devil_in_the_Dark_%28episode%29) can live for up to 50,000 years. They are only listed as Federation members in novels, but from their only onscreen appearance it is a fair assumption they joined. I know of no other Federation species that can live that long, though certain species like the [Douwd](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Douwd), which live in the Federation in secret, can live longer.

Comment: If I can remember that TOS episode correctly, they didn't look like such sentient to join Federation..

Comment: @SachinShekhar: Whaaa? They form an alliance with Human colonists for a joint mining operation at the end of the episode. There were also plans to have a Horta Ambassador on Earth during *The Voyage Home*, but the costume couldn't be prepared on time. Where are you getting that they're not sentient? Or that they wouldn't join the Federation?

Comment: They were bugs... The rocky bugs!

Comment: @SachinShekhar: please. That sort of language is very offensive to [Petra-](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrology)[Insectiod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insectoid)-Americans.

Comment: @SachinShekhar: I fail to see how being a "rocky bug" would disqualify a species from Federation membership.

Comment: Man, you look like diplomat.. See the joke here.

Comment: I may be missing something here. What joke? And I am trained as a diplomat, actually, though I didn't bother to go on with it.